# When does a linear polynomial $p(t_i)$ divide $p(t_i^2)$?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, divisibility

Let $p=\sum_{i=1}^na_it_i$ be a linear polynomial and $q=\sum_{i=1}^na_it_i^2$. For which tuples $(a_1,...,a_n)\in\mathbb C^n$ does $p$ divide $q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $p$ is either of the form $at_i$ or $a(t_i-t_j)$ for some $a\in \mathbb C$.

Proof: by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, all polynomials work. If $n=2$, and assuming $a_1,a_2$ are nonzero, only $a(t_1-t_2)$ is possible since $a_1t_1^2 +a_2t_2^2=(\sqrt{a_1}t_1+i\sqrt{a_2}t_2)(\sqrt{a_1}t_1-i\sqrt{a_2}t_2)$ and so $a_1t_1+a_2t_2$ divides one of the two, so $(a_1/a_2)^2=-(a_1/a_2)$ and therefore $a_1=-a_2$. Finally notice that if $p$ has the property, then so does $q(x_1,...,x_{n-1})=p(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$, so it suffices to show that no polynomial with $3$ nonzero coefficients satisfies the property. Assume wlog that $n=1$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are nonzero. Then, substituting $x_3=0$ we get $a_2=-a_1$ from the $n=2$ case. By symmetry any pair satisfies $a_i=-a_j$. But this is impossible.